# ARIMA in Python

Tags: python, time-series

I am new to Python. Now I am learning the ARIMA model and its implementation in Python. I watched the Youtube video in the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWRsxhUzpxk&index=3&list=PLybkqEz6g9JhrX5riJSa2C76AtMa0KIhp

I still have some puzzles about ARMA, epecially how to determine best p and q. In the video, I want to try different p and q pairs and choose based on aic rule as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
p = 1
q = 1
arma_1 = sm.tsa.ARMA(data, (p,q)).fit() # data is the dataset of time series
aic_min = arma_1.aic

for i in range(1,6) :
    for j in range(1,6) :
        arma = sm.tsa.ARMA(data, (i,j)).fit()
        aic = arma.aic
        if aic < aic_min :
            aic_min = aic
            p = i
            q = j

print (i,j,aic_min)
```

Traceback shows: The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary
You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order, or you can
pass your own start_params. 
  My question is: (1) what does this traceback mean? (2) Is my method right to find right (p,q) pairs? Is there any more convenient method?

Comment: And can you also recommend some books about ARIMA in python? It will be better if it contains not only theory but also some examples with Python code available.

Comment: To be stationary, the AR coefs must lie in the open interval (-1,1). Your data must look more like a random-walk or power function, and therefore the AR coefs >= |1|. That issue aside, your idea of looping over orders of p & q is correct, but you're ignoring the possibility of a pure AR(p) or MA(q) model by excluding the possibility that p=0 or q=0.

Comment: I have done some changes. First, I used 1st-order difference and it is stationary through ADF test. Second, I changed i and j from 0 and added if statement to omit when i=j=0. However, the same warning appears again.

Comment: I have checked it again. The problem appears when j>2, I let j = 1 or 0, the loop can find the best order. However, if I let j>2, the program will stop because of error.

Comment: OK, then you are zeroing in on the issue. If you are also an `R` user, you could try the `auto.arima` function from the `forecast` package, and set `stationary=FALSE` to allow for non-stationary models.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. Can you help explain "zeroing in on the issue" a little? Thanks very much!